# Why is this conversion method not compiling?

Tags: c++

Why is the following not compiling?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_void_v<T>
    || ( std::is_array_v<T> && is_json_allowed<element_type_t<T>>::value )
    || std::is_same_v<T,std::string> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>
> {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_json_allowed_v = is_json_allowed<T>::value;

class Node
{
public:

    Node()
    :
        m_type(typeid(void))
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<is_json_allowed_v<T>,Node&> operator=(const T& rhs)
    {
        m_type = typeid(T);
        m_data.resize(sizeof(T));
        std::memcpy(&m_data[0],&rhs,sizeof(T));
    }

    template<typename T>
    Node& operator=(const Node& rhs)
    {
        m_type = rhs.m_type;
        m_data = rhs.m_data;
    }

private:
    std::type_index m_type;
    std::vector<int8_t> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_json_allowed_v<unsigned int> << std::endl;
    Node x = 34u;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (Mingw-Builds 7.3.0) complains about a conversion from `unsigned int` to a non-scalar type `Node`. Which I don't understand, the assignment operator should kick in with the value of `34u`.

It also complains about a request for member `begin` in `__cont`, which is a non-class type `const unsigned int`. Which I think means that the `element_type_t` is kicking in even though the `unsigned int` type is clearly not an array.

Comment: Under rules of the language, `Node x = 34u` does not involve any `Node::operator=()`.   Instead it constructs a `Node` using a constructor of `Node` that accepts an `unsigned` as an argument.   Your `Node` class has no such constructor.

Comment: The fact that `std::is_array_v<T>` is false will not prevent `is_json_allowed<element_type_t<T>>::value` from getting instantiated. Short circuiting in template deduction is not a thing.

Comment: @Peter how can I invoke an assignment operator?

Comment: @super is there another way to do what I'm trying that doesn't involve relying on short circuiting?

Comment: I think you meant for your `Node`-specific assignment operator to be an overload or specialization (preferably overload), and it is neither.

Comment: @NeomerArcana  *how can I invoke an assignment operator?* -- By performing an assignment, `Node x;  x = 34u;`

Comment: Oooh. Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I'm a bit slow today

Comment: To get it to work with `Node x = 34u`, you can use a constructors, as @Peter mentioned. Although style-wise, [it is often better to make the conversion explicit](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ro-conversion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not rely on short circuiting in the template deduction you can use SFINAE and a help struct like this.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct not_json_allowed {};

template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct element_type {
    using type = not_json_allowed;
};

template <typename T>
struct element_type<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>> {
    using type = element_type_t<T>;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed : std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_void_v<T>
    || std::is_same_v<T,std::string> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>
> {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_json_allowed_v = is_json_allowed<T>::value || is_json_allowed<typename element_type<T>::type>::value;

class Node
{
public:

    Node()
    :
        m_type(typeid(void))
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<is_json_allowed_v<T>,Node&> operator=(const T& rhs)
    {
        m_type = typeid(T);
        m_data.resize(sizeof(T));
        std::memcpy(&m_data[0],&rhs,sizeof(T));
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Node& operator=(const Node& rhs)
    {
        m_type = rhs.m_type;
        m_data = rhs.m_data;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::type_index m_type;
    std::vector<int8_t> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_json_allowed_v<unsigned int> << std::endl;
    Node x;
    x = 34u;

    return 0;
}
```

I also changed main to use an assignement, another option would be to add an equivalent template constructor in `Node`.

Comment: @NeomerArcana I'm sure the concept of using a helper struct and SFINAE is this way works. If the rest of the code does what you want it to is another question, one I can't really answer with given information.

Comment: @NeomerArcana Here is the [code with some added print outs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m4RlNYxA96w0HBxJ). Not sure exactly what you are looking for though.